# How to substitute value of a LINQ subQuery

Tags: sql-server, linq

How to Substitute the value of ProductID in 2nd Query?

```
var pid= from t in Products where t.Name == "Cable Lock" select  t.ProductID
```

---

```
var f=from k in SalesOrderDetails where k.ProductID= select k;
f.Dump();
```

Comment: You could try using a `join`

Comment: Yes...Join i know But How to substitute Instead of a join I tried this var f=from k in SalesOrderDetails where k.ProductID= (from t in Products where t.Name =="Cable Lock" select t.ProductID)

select k;
f.Dump();

Comment: But am getting this error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'

Comment: @user3933885 - Check my answer, you were missing the `FirstOrDefault` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var orderDetails = from o in SalesOrderDetails
                   join p in Products on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID
                   where (p.Name == "Cable Lock")
                   select o;
```

or using a subquery:

```
var orderDetails = from o in SalesOrderDetails
                   where Products.Any(p => p.Name == "Cable Lock")
                   select o;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not going for `Joins` but if I will go with your logic, you are missing `FirstOrDefault` in your code, You can do this:-

```
var pid = (from t in products where t.Name == "Cable Lock" select t.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can use this `productId` in your next query:-

```
var f= from k in SalesOrderDetails where k.ProductId == pid  select k;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that `var pid= from t in Products where t.Name == "Cable Lock" select  t.ProductID` is of type `IQueryable<int>` which is an `IEnumerable` not a single value.

So you can pick one of the following

```
var pid = (from p in Products
          where p.Name == "Cable Lock"
          select p.Id).Single();
var f = from k in SalesOrderDetails where k.ProductID= select k;
```

OR

```
var pid = from p in Products
          where p.Name == "Cable Lock"
          select p.Id;
var f = from k in SalesOrderDetails where pid.Contains(k.ProductID) select k;
```